# Remove last separator from menu

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am creating menu in joomla (do not worry if you not know joomla this question is HTML-CSS related).

There is separator`(like "|")` between each menu.

this is my code
also on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WRuTC/

HTML

```
<div id="footerlinks">        <div class="module">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td nowrap="nowrap"><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=11">HOME</a><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=12">ABOUT WLB</a><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=13">KEY PERSONNEL</a><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=14">CAPABILITIES</a><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=15">PROJECTS</a><a class="mainlevel" href="/Parthvi/joomla/WLB/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=16">CONTACT US</a></td></tr></tbody></table>                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

               </div>
```

CSS

```
    #footerlinks .module td a {
    border-right: 1px solid #79797A;
    color: #515152;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 42px !important;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now, the problem is this css puts separator at right side of menu, and i do not want the last separator(not want right most separator) how can i ?
any css selector?

Comment: i do not want to use ul li type menu

Comment: 2012 is coming, and you're still using `table` for menu layout.

Comment: @JeaffreyGilbert no i am not its joomla default menu :( what can i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #footerlinks .module td a:last-child{border:0}
```

But it will not work in ie<8. If you want support also ie7 place border on left and then

```
 #footerlinks .module td a:first-child{border:0}
```

If you want to support ie6 you have to add class or style to last  (you can use eq. jQuery for fixing it).

Comment: @AjayPatel does not work in ie-7 and 8 so use first-child instead!

Comment: You can use border-left: 1px solid; and margin-left: -1px; with overflow: hidden; on the parent container to make it work in all manner of ancient browsers.

Answer (score 1):

you should set the first `td:first-child`

`:first-child` works in all browser!

```
#footerlinks .module td a {
    border-left: 1px solid #79797A;
    color: #515152;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 42px !important;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footerlinks .module td a:first-child {
    border-left: 0px solid #79797A;

}
```

[fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WRuTC/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3's `last-child` declaration to target the last item on your menu, like so:

```
#footerlinks .module td a:last-child {
    border-right:none;
}
```

Granted, that is not highly supported in older browsers, in which case you can just target the menu-item class and remove the border from there. You can take a look at the source of your page and take a look at the class added automatically by joomla for that menu item, e.g. item-24, item-23, etc.., and just do this:

```
#footerlinks .module td .item-24 {
    border-right:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove border from `#footerlinks .module td a` and add this

```
#footerlinks .module td a + a { border-left:1px solid #79797A; }
```

Comment: not working i can not see any of separator, try jsfiddle link

Comment: I thought each `<a>` is separated with `<td>`. It is updated: http://jsfiddle.net/WRuTC/2/.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footerlinks .module td a:last-child {
   border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       #footerlinks .module td a {
    border-left: 1px solid #79797A;
    color: #515152;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 42px !important;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footerlinks .module td a.first-child {
    border-left: none;

}
```